# Using a default value in CMD Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can someone help me with my batch. I'm trying to have an escape at the beginning of my batch but it's not working. I'm sure it's simple but I'm not a regular user of this type of programming.

```
cls
@echo off
set usr_out=y
set /p usr_out=Press [N] to cancel:

if NOT %usr_out% == Y goto myend
if NOT %usr_out% == y goto myend

echo in

pause
exit

:myend
echo out
pause
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to detail that the code above only goes to the `echo out` line when I don't enter a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the default value of `%usr_out%` to a **lowercase** `y`:

```
set usr_out=y
```

But then check if the variable is **unequal** to an **uppercase** `Y`:

```
if NOT %usr_out% == Y goto myend
```

Since `y` and `Y` are indeed unequal, your script correctly jumps to `:myend` at this point.

You need to fix your logic here. If you want to skip over a code block when all of a given number of conditions are not met you have to use something like this in batch:

```
if "%usr_out%"=="y" goto continue
if "%usr_out%"=="Y" goto continue
goto myend
:continue
```

However, in your particular case you can use a simpler approach, because you only need a case-insensitive check for one single letter:

```
if /i not "%usr_out%"=="y" goto myend
```

---

On a different note: instead of a plain `exit` I'd recommend using either `goto :eof` (jump to the end of the script) or `exit /b` (exit the batch script without terminating `cmd.exe`). Otherwise running the script manually in a command prompt might inadvertently terminate the command prompt window.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I didn't know about the case-insensitive option, such a silly error. Also I appreciate your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

simply the problem is that you take spaces between "==" and other command or words like :

```
if NOT %usr_out% == Y goto myend
```

but you must use this :

```
if NOT %usr_out%==Y goto myend
```

Answer (score 0):

To the second half of your question:

> when I don't enter a value

You can add this check:

```
set /p usr_out=Press [N] to cancel:
if "x"=="x%usr_out%" set usr_out=y
```

This checks whether the variable has no value, or the empty string as a value.